# FLASK entender a documentação

Tags: python, flask, documentação

O flask possui alguma estrutura padrão de pastas, tipos de arquivos e funções?

Por exemplo esse esquema de pastas é padrão para qualquer projeto ou é um modelo simplificado?

---

```
home/user/Projects/flask-tutorial
├── flaskr/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── db.py
│   ├── schema.sql
│   ├── auth.py
│   ├── blog.py
│   ├── templates/
│   │   ├── base.html
│   │   ├── auth/
│   │   │   ├── login.html
│   │   │   └── register.html
│   │   └── blog/
│   │       ├── create.html
│   │       ├── index.html
│   │       └── update.html
│   └── static/
│       └── style.css
├── tests/
│   ├── conftest.py
│   ├── data.sql
│   ├── test_factory.py
│   ├── test_db.py
│   ├── test_auth.py
│   └── test_blog.py
├── venv/
├── setup.py
└── MANIFEST.in
```

Comment: Se ler a [documentação](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/tutorial/layout/) verá que *"Um aplicativo Flask pode ser tão simples quanto um único arquivo. No entanto, à medida que um projeto cresce, torna-se difícil manter todo o código em um arquivo"* e continua....

Comment: *"O diretório do projeto conterá:flaskr/, um pacote Python que contém o código e os arquivos do seu aplicativo. tests/, um diretório contendo módulos de teste.
venv/, um ambiente virtual Python onde o Flask e outras dependências são instaladas.
Arquivos de instalação informando ao Python como instalar seu projeto.
Configuração de controle de versão, como git . Você deve criar o hábito de usar algum tipo de controle de versão para todos os seus projetos, não importa o tamanho.
Quaisquer outros arquivos de projeto que você possa adicionar no futuro."*

Comment: Se quer uma estrutura de projetos modular, a própria documentação possui uma maneira "padrão" de estruturar aplicações, ela se chama `blueprint`. Segue a [referência](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/blueprints/#)